# Understanding where my R libraries are being installed to on EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance that I can save as my own AMI, with all of the softwares installed already so I don't have to redo all of this stuff everytime I need a new EC2 instance.

One thing I'm trying to understand is where all of my R libraries are being installed to... When I install a library, I receive the following:

```
[root@ip-myip] R -e "install.packages('jsonlite', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"



R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages('jsonlite', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1096810 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘jsonlite’ ...
** package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c base64.c -o base64.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c collapse_array.c -o collapse_array.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c collapse_object.c -o collapse_object.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c collapse_pretty.c -o collapse_pretty.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c escape_chars.c -o escape_chars.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c integer64_to_na.c -o integer64_to_na.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c is_datelist.c -o is_datelist.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c is_recordlist.c -o is_recordlist.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c is_scalarlist.c -o is_scalarlist.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c modp_numtoa.c -o modp_numtoa.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c null_to_na.c -o null_to_na.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c num_to_char.c -o num_to_char.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c parse.c -o parse.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c prettify.c -o prettify.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c push_parser.c -o push_parser.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c r-base64.c -o r-base64.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c register.c -o register.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c row_collapse.c -o row_collapse.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c transpose_list.c -o transpose_list.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c validate.c -o validate.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl.c -o yajl/yajl.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_alloc.c -o yajl/yajl_alloc.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_buf.c -o yajl/yajl_buf.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_encode.c -o yajl/yajl_encode.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_gen.c -o yajl/yajl_gen.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_lex.c -o yajl/yajl_lex.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_parser.c -o yajl/yajl_parser.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c yajl/yajl_tree.c -o yajl/yajl_tree.o
ar rcs libstatyajl.a yajl/yajl.o yajl/yajl_alloc.o yajl/yajl_buf.o yajl/yajl_encode.o yajl/yajl_gen.o yajl/yajl_lex.o yajl/yajl_parser.o yajl/yajl_tree.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o jsonlite.so base64.o collapse_array.o collapse_object.o collapse_pretty.o escape_chars.o integer64_to_na.o is_datelist.o is_recordlist.o is_scalarlist.o modp_numtoa.o null_to_na.o num_to_char.o parse.o prettify.o push_parser.o r-base64.o register.o row_collapse.o transpose_list.o validate.o -L. -lstatyajl -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/lib64/R/library/jsonlite/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘jsonlite’
    finding HTML links ... done
    base64                                  html  
    flatten                                 html  
    fromJSON                                html  
    prettify                                html  
    rbind_pages                             html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpZ3IcD8/R.INSTALL21106d208413/jsonlite/man/rbind_pages.Rd:22: missing file link ‘rbind’
    read_json                               html  
    serializeJSON                           html  
    stream_in                               html  
    unbox                                   html  
    validate                                html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (jsonlite)
Making 'packages.html' ... done

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpRRGy3s/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
> 
>
```

So the answer seems obvious... *The downloaded source packages are in ‘/tmp/RtmpRRGy3s/downloaded_packages’* Wonderful! However, when I cd into my /tmp directory, I see the following...

```
[root@ip-myip /]# cd tmp
[root@ip-myip tmp]# ls
hsperfdata_root  rstudio-rsession  Rtmp49pRek  Rtmp9cGn9Z  RtmpzATaBO  Rtmpzmgmqv
```

Although similar, none of those directories match the RtmpRRGy3s from the install command. Also, all of the other folders starting with Rtmp... are empty!

I like trying to understand these types of problems, and since I'll be using this AMI over and over again, I'd really like to know where my R libraries are being installed. Any help is appreciated:

EDIT - here is my home directory on my EC2 instance:

```
[root@ip-myip /]# ls
bin   cgroup  etc   lib    local       media  opt   root  sbin     srv  tmp  var
boot  dev     home  lib64  lost+found  mnt    proc  run   selinux  sys  usr
```

and here's what's hidden in my root directory:

```
cd root
ls -a
.   .bash_history  .bash_profile  .cshrc  .RData  .tcshrc
..  .bash_logout   .bashrc        .pki    .ssh    .viminfo
```

Comment: In R, if you run `.libPaths()` it will show all the places it looks for packages. By default, R installs all new packages to the first path that `.libPaths()` returns.

Comment: Also running `installed.packages()` will return a matrix with a column named "LibPath" that will show the directory where each package is installed.